Asymptotic for counting irreducible $0$-$1$ polynomials?
Consider integer polynomials of degree $n$ such that all coefficients are $0$ or $1$.
The so-called $0$-$1$ polynomials.
For instance $1 + x^5 + x^{83} + x^{90}.$
We can list them and order them by setting $x=2$ because that is the binary expansion with $n$ bits.
$$ 0 \implies 0 $$
$$1 \implies 1 $$
$$2\implies x $$
$$3 \implies 1 +x $$
$$4 \implies x^2 $$
$$5 \implies 1 + x^2 $$
etc
Now there are clearly $2^n -1$ nonzero $0$-$1$ polynomials up to degree $n-1$.
Let $\pi_{01}(n) $ count the number of irreducible polynomials up to the first $n$ ordered as above but starting at $1$.
So the $5$th is $1 + x^2$ and then $\pi_{01}(5) = {x,1+x,1+x^2} = 3$.
We do not count the $0$ or $1$ as irreducible polynomials.
Now it is clear that
$$\pi(n) \leq \pi_{01}(n)$$
where $\pi(n)$ is the normal prime counting function.
But what exactly are the asymptotics for $\pi_{01}(n)$ ?
Similarly,
Let $p_{01}(n)$ be the $n$th irreducible in the list.
So
$$\pi_{01}(p_{01}(n)) = p_{01}(pi_{01}(n)) = n$$
Clearly
$$ p_{01}(n) \leq p_n$$
where $p_n$ is the $n$ th prime.
So the sum of reciprocals of $p_{01}(n)$ diverges.
But what exactly are the asymptotics for $p_{01}(n)$ ?

You might look at OEIS sequence A255574. The graph looks suspiciously close to a straight line.

They are not "zero minus one polynomials", they are "zero-one polynomials". It's a hyphen, not a minus sign, so it should not be part of the math formula.

Sorry and thanks for the edit @ArturoMagidin

This question (in a somewhat more general form) was studied by this 2019 paper by Breuillard and Varjú, most of whose results rely on the extended Riemann hypothesis (more precisely, RH for the Dedekind zeta functions of all number fields generated by the polynomials in question).  Under this hypothesis, their Corollary 4 states that the proportion of $0$-$1$ polynomials of the form $x^d + \dots + 1$ which are irreducible is asymptotically $1 - \sqrt{2/\pi d} + O(1/d)$.  In particular, almost all $0$-$1$ polynomials of high degree are irreducible, except for those divisible by $x$.
Since all the polynomials with no constant term (and degree $> 1$) are reducible, this gives
$$
\pi_{01}(2^d) = 2^{d-1} (1 - \sqrt{2/\pi d} + O(1/d)),
$$
conditional on ERH.  This in turn suggests the asymptotic
$$\pi_{01}(n) \overset{?}{=} \frac{n}{2} (1 - \sqrt{2/\pi \log_2(n)} + O(1/\log_2(n)),
$$
although it's not obvious to me whether we can expect the irreducible polynomials to be equidistributed across the "interval" from $x^n$ to $x^{n+1}$.

Candidate for accept ...
